# Form not submitting in Chrome and Safari

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome, safari

I am new to PHP, so I am not sure what is wrong with the code. I have tested the form in Internet Explorer, FireFox, Chrome, and Safari and it works great in both I.E. and FireFox, but it doesn't work in Chrome or Safari. In both Chrome and Safari I get the successfully submitted page, but I do not get an email sent to me.

**HTML page:**

```
 <form name="balxfrform" action="baltransfer.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="_SUBJECT" value="Transfer Request Form">

 <b>* Name:</b> <input name="name" type="text" size="60"><br>
 <b>* Email:</b> <input name="email" type="text" size="60"><br>
 <b>Member Number (Last 3 Digits) XXX:</b> <input name="account" type="text" size="10"><br>
 <b>Card Number:</b> <input name="ccnumber" type="text" size="40"><br>
 <b>Phone Number:</b> <input name="pnumber" type="text" size="20"><br>
 <b>Best Time to reach you<sup>1</sup>:</b> <input name="time" type="text" size="40"><br>
 <b>* I agree to the terms and conditions listed below:</b> Yes <input name="terms" type="checkbox" value="Yes"><br>      

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

**PHP page:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "email@test.com";
    $email_subject = "Transfer Request Form";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.<br /><br /> ";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix the error(s).<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['account']) ||
       !isset($_POST['ccnumber']) ||
       !isset($_POST['pnumber']) ||
       !isset($_POST['time']) ||
       !isset($_POST['terms'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $account = $_POST['account']; // not required
    $ccnumber = $_POST['ccnumber']; // not required
    $pnumber = $_POST['pnumber']; // not required
    $time = $_POST['time']; // not required
    $terms = $_POST['terms']; // required
    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    if(!isset($terms)) {
        $error_message .=  'You must agree to the Terms and Conditions to continue.';
    }
    $email_message = "Form Details Below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Member Number XXX: ".clean_string($account)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Card Number: ".clean_string($ccnumber)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($pnumber)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Best Time to be Reached: ".clean_string($time)."\n"."\n";
    $email_message .= "Agree to Terms and Conditions: ".clean_string($terms)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: email@test.com'.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your error log? PHP doesn't have anything to do with browsers most of the time, you know.

Comment: @Barmar thanks it worked. The only issue I seem to be having now is I asked a co-worker who has i.e.10 to test the form. He gets the successfully completed page, but I do not get an email. Would you have any idea why this would be happening? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What worked? I didn't post an answer. Check your PHP error log to see if something is going wrong.

Comment: Isn't that the problem you originally reported? Why do you say it worked if the mail still isn't going through?

Comment: @Barmar You changed the code for me and for some reason what you sent plus everyone's comments got deleted somehow. My original problem was when I tested the form in FireFox and I.E. it worked but not in Chrome and Safari. You changed the code and when I updated it on my end, it then worked in all of the browsers. However I am testing with i.e. 11 and my co-worker has i.e. 10 and it still doesn't send the email to me. I was just wondering if you knew what would be causing that.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to your code, all I did was neaten the indentation and get rid of lots of blank lines.

Comment: The only comments that were removed were on an answer. The poster deleted his answer because he realized it was wrong.

Comment: Check the mail log on your server to see if the mail was sent. Maybe it's being stopped by a spam filter on the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there will be nothing to do with the PHP part. PHP is run on the server side. Since one browsers interpret HTML code differently, this might be an HTML syntax issue of your HTML form. You may try validating your HTML. Try this [tool](http://validator.w3.org/)  .

Answer (score 0):

Try following solutions
1.) add @ before mail() function 
ex : @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

2.)`if (!mail(...)) {
   // again Call your code
}`